# Subscribing to MSMQ over the internet

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq, servicebus

I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this problem. Is there a *good* way to subscribe to a MSMQ through the internet? Ideally I need security both in authentication and encryption for this connection. But I would like the subscriber to act just like any other client that would be subscribed on the local network. I believe I have a couple of options here

- Expose the MSMQ ports publicly
- Put the MSMQ behind some type of WCF service (not sure if that works for a subscriber)

What other options do I have? We're sitting in a .NET environment and the main problem domain that is trying to be solved is to change the remote connections from a pulling system to an event based system to reduce the load on the main server.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use a queue ON the Internet.

I work at Microsoft and my team owns MSMQ and we also own the Windows Azure Service Bus service. For the scenario you describe you may want to take a look at using a Service Bus Queue, which has not only the advantage of being reachable for Internet senders but also eliminates the need to create inbound firewall rules on the receive side.

More here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-queues/

Answer (score 0):

The most natural option will be to use MSMQ over http, which is a feature of MSMQ:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164041.aspx

The alternative would be to create an http WCF service possibly with duplex polling and use WS-Routing to an MSMQ WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Gateway](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/gateway/) feature of NServiceBus.